# tf.keras.utils.get_file error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

everyone,

Recently I start to program with tensorflow 2.10.0, have the following codes in my ipynb file (Jupyter Notebook file):

```
if not data_dir.exists():
    tf.keras.utils.get_file('free-spoken-digit-dataset-master.zip',origin="https://codeload.github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset/zip/refs/heads/master",extract=True,cache_dir='.',cache_subdir='data')
```

I want to download the file free-spoken-digit-dataset-master.zip from the URL `https://codeload.github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset/zip/refs/heads/master`, after running the codes the following error message is displayed:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Has anyone faced this issue or similar issue before?

Also tried the following codes:

```
tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin="https://github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset/archive/v1.0.9.tar.gz",extract=True,cache_dir='.',cache_subdir='data')
```

The same error message was displayed:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you deeply, @TFer2, Stackoverflow is a good forum for software developers, people can almost find each answer here.
I already turned to other projects now. The correct way to loading the spoken_digit dataset is:

dataset,dataset_info=tfds.load("spoken_digit",split=['train'],as_supervised=True,with_info=True)

or

dataset=TFDatasets.builder('spoken_digit').as_dataset()['train']

.

Answer (score 0):

This code is running absolutely fine when I tried the same in jupyter notebook using `TensorFlow 2.10`. Please check the screenshot below:[image]

There might be an issue with the tensorflow installation. Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to re-verify if you have installed tensorflow properly in your system with compatible `python` version between `3.7 - 3.10` for `TensorFlow 2.10`.